# Bitrix замена %2F

Tags: php, битрикс, url

Кто подскажет где искать, что бы заменить %2F в url на дефис ? cms bitrix, если пройти по ссылке http://domisad.ua/catalog/plitkorezy/filter/diametr_disk-is-400/dry_wet_swaing-is-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82+%2F+%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/apply/ то выдаст ошибку, хотя если поменять %2F на "-" то ссылка работает.

Comment: судя по ссылке, вы что-то выбирали в смарт фильтре, попробуйте, посмотреть символьный код раздела(товаров), и пересоздайте фасетный индекс

Comment: http://domisad.ua/catalog/plitkorezy/filter/diametr_disk-is-400/dry_wet_swaing-is-нет+%2F+есть/apply/

вот это выдает, меняем %2F - ccылка работает, пытаюсь найти место где формируется url

Comment: символьный код раздела не смотрели?

Comment: дело в том что мне нужно убрать генерацию таких ссылок, seo отдел попросили, скорее всего где-то не правильно работает модуль фильтров. Если бы я перехватил формирование url я бы его декодил и менял %2F на дефис, ссылка была рабочая

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=42&LESSON_ID=5364

Comment: Нашел, посмотрел, там ничего не обычно, все записано хорошо
значит формируется ссылка которая не должна формироваться) буду дальше разбираться